# AWS Lambda (Node) from VPC with NAT times out connecting to SFTP

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sftp, amazon-vpc

I know questions of this type have been asked and answered elsewhere but I still have not managed to find a solution for my problem.

I have a simple Lambda function that needs to access an external SFTP server. I have configured a static IP address for the VPC it's in according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/generate-a-static-outbound-ip-address-using-a-lambda-function-amazon-vpc-and-a-serverless-architecture.html.

[image: VPC config]

However when I test the SFTP connection I am getting a timeout (when I test the Lambda locally from my laptop it works). I have run the Reachability Analyzer which seems to confirm that the network (private-subnet -> NAT -> public-subnet -> Internet Gateway) are configured correctly.

[image: Reachability Analysis]

Would anyone have any insight into what the issue might be. I am a bit desperate at this point as I have spent so long trying to figure this out and need to get this up and running.

Also within this app I can successfully make https callouts (even without the custom VPC config above). So I think I must be missing something simple.

Comment: Why did you place lambda in a VPC? Do not do this, and your lambda will have internet access.

Comment: Hi @Marcin, I need to have a static IP so that it can be whitelisted for the production SFTP server I need to access. That's why I followed the AWS article linked above. However even if I don't have it in a custom VPC, it still times out to the SFTP server.

Comment: If it still does not work outside of VPC, then probably your SFTP service is blocking the connections.

Comment: I'm testing with my personal SFTP server (so no IP restrictions). Access from my laptop works find but when trying to access from the VPC there is no log of any traffic.

Comment: Start without the Lambda function connected to the VPC. This way, it eliminates a lot of the networking configuration. Once you get it working that way, you can add things back. Try connecting from an EC2 instance to your personal SFTP server -- it will be easier to diagnose problems. It will probably be due to the fact that your laptop does not have an actual Public IP address and would need port-forwarding through your router. You'll probably end up spending more time trying to diagnose the connection to your own SFTP server than trying to get the _real_ connection sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [@John Rotenstein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/174777/john-rotenstein) for suggesting I go back to basics. It allowed me to discover that I was doing something dumb in my Node app and my VPC config (to get a static IP) was in fact correct!

An odd thing I noticed was when I created an EC2 instance using Amazon Linux, the SFTP connection to my server resulted in "Connection refused. Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer". Creating an EC2 instance with the same default settings but with Ubuntu allowed be to connect successfully to my SFTP server.

One other question if I could ask it here. If I want to have a "siloed tenancy" where each tenant has their own VPC (quite strict data compliance requirements), is it possible for them to share the private & public subnet, NAT gateway (for the static IP address).